# How to see the permissions of an user over a file in Linux?

Tags: linux

How can I see the permissions of an user over a file (or directiory) in Linux, I know that with "ls -l" I can see the permissions of my user over files. Is there any way to do this with other users without logging in?

Comment: [Here's a helpful picture.](http://linuxcommand.org/images/permissions_diagram.gif)

Comment: user over a file? What are you trying to ask? what does `ls -l` not give you that you want?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions you see on the files when you do `ls -l` are the permission settings on the file for every user and group on that *nix system. ***The file permissions settings are universal, and will not change based on which user is logged in to the system.*** Of course, file permissions of a file or directory can be changed by a user with the correct privileges (and those changes will be universal across every user and group).

The file permission settings set the permissions controls for three types of entities that may or may not access the file. The three entities are the user, the group, and everybody else. The file permission settings you see when you do `ls -l` are describing the permissions settings for each respective entity.

I'd read through [this guide](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions) to get a better understanding of how permissions work in a *nix system.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you do "ls -l" it return something like that :

```
-rwxrw-r-- 10 user group    252 Jan 13 08:43:10 text
```

Each columns stand for :

- File permissions
- Number of links to the file
- Owner name
- Owner group
- File size
- Time of last modification
- File/directory name

The file permissions part can be divided in four parts :

- First character which describe the type of file ("-" is for a regular file)
- Then there is three parts of three characters each :

  - The first is the permissions for the owner of the file
  - The second is the permissions for all the members of the owner group of the file
  - The third is the permissions for everyone else

In the example we have :

- `-` The file is a regular one
- `rwx` The owner is "user" and he has the rights to read ("r"), write ("w") and execute ("x") on the file
- `rw-` The group is "group" and every user on that group can read and write on the file but not execute it
- `r--` Everyone else can just read the file and cannot write on it or execute it

To list all the group an user is member of use the command "groups user" (replace "user" by the name of the user).